# Issues with Nib

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I am currently loading a nib dynamically as a client wants the language to be selectable in the app.

So I have something like this

```
UIViewController * viewController = [UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Controller" WithBundle: languageBundle];
```

However none of the image in the Nib seem to load. Is their a quick solution to this ? or would I have to store all my translations in a strings file and switch to having one nib which the translations are pumped into via the awakeFromNib Method. This would take a lot of time so I am looking to see if their is an easy fix for the images not loading.

Comment: Can you elaborate the question?

Comment: Well loading the `nib` from a specific bundle will also effect the loading of images, since those will also be loaded from the given bundle. you just try and solve the language loading on a different way, by setting the preferred language in the userdefaults.